# The CSS does not contain a reference to the background image

Tags: apex, trailhead

I am doing `TrailHead tutorial` from the link: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/quickstart-lightning-components/steps/quickstart-lightning-components6. While taking the challenge I see the below error.

**How we can make the component active?**

[image]

I've already written the correct code.

```
.THIS {
    background:url("") no-repeat center center;
    min-height:100%;
    background-size:cover;
    color: darkblue;
    font: Arial;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    }
    .THIS ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .THIS h3 {
    font: bold 20px/1.5 Arial;
    }
    .THIS .minli {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    width:95%;
}
.THIS li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Screen shot for reference:**

[image]

**MyContactList.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.myAction}" value="{!this}" />
    <aura:attribute name="contacts" type="Contact[]" />
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Please post your code as text and not an image.

Comment: Was unable to paste code with URL https://bit.ly/1Dy6Eji, hence provided URL here.

Comment: Please suggest the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the image you are clicking on style from the app bundle.

For this challenge you should created component and access the style from the component bundle.

Click on

> File --> new --> lightning component

and name the component MyContactList and click on style from the component bundle.

Similar question : https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BTRqIAO

Comment: I've already created MyContactList lightning component, but still issue. Pls see updated screen shot..

Comment: can you close other tabs and just show the mycontactlist component tab ?